# Include Bitbucket Approve Plugin to Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to include the [Bitbucket Approve Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Approve+Plugin) into one of my Jenkins Pipeline steps. Is this possible?

```
node {
stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm

stage 'Build'
    bat 'nuget restore SolutionName.sln'
    bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" SolutionName.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\" /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

stage 'Archive'
    archive 'ProjectName/bin/Release/**'
```

So if this would be my pipeline. How would I add the plugin to a stage?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60989?filter=-2) for that issue. you can vote for it.